# The state-preserving dictionary isn't preserving state

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have followed the tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967548%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to preserve state between pages.

However, the *State* dictionary is ALWAYS empty, when I programatically navigate back to this page! What seems to be the problem here?

I have tested this behaviour on Emulator 8.0.10322 720P.

This is what I do:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            State["IS"] = ResultsList.ItemsSource;
            State["SI"] = ResultsList.SelectedItem;
            State["dgtest"] = new Data();
            State["test"] = "gi2";
        }
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (e.IsNavigationInitiator && e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            ResultsList.ItemsSource = (System.Collections.IList) State["IS"];
            ResultsList.SelectedItem = State["SI"];
        }
    }
```

The objects in the *ItemsSource* are of type Data, defined here:

```
[DataContract]
public class Data
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Datum { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:** To programatically navigate back, I'm calling `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/mypages/page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant, but maybe `Data` should be serializable, for they write _The objects that the user places in this dictionary must be serializable._ on the [doc page on `State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.state.aspx).

Comment: `However, the State dictionary is ALWAYS empty, when I navigate back to this page` Is it? You're not even reading it when you're navigating back, is that on purpose?

Comment: @KooKiz Yes. I'm not having these problems when tapping the button "Back". I'm having problems when I _programatically_ navigate back to the page. I've updated the question.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I can't seem to put [Serializable] or similar tags before the class definition, because they don't exist.

Comment: "I'm having problems when I programatically navigate back to the page". You're navigating FORWARD when calling NavigationService.Navigate(...). In this case the page (together with State) is newly instanciated and thus empty.

Comment: @HDWProduction I see. I deem your answer correct. Now I only need an alternative solution to this problem. Does a Pivot Page with two "subpages" preserve state when I transition from one to another?

Comment: Navigating through Pivot items will technically work, but I guess that it's not what a user would expect. I see two solutions: Either use NavigationService.GoBack() or implement your own State dictionary.